# Temp stored procedure before BeginTry Begin TRANSACTION causing issues

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a script to make 5 different columns nullable (we want to make sure that the system runs perfectly before we do the hard drop). My stored procedure works flawlessly and has been tested.

However when I try to run this script as a whole, it fails or does not make the columns nullable. I believe it is due to the `BEGIN TRY` and `BEGIN TRANSACTION` that it is failing. It seems that it is trying to create the stored procedure on every run?

1. What would be the correct way of create a temporary stored procedure at the start of a script and then running a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` to make these columns nullable?
2. Should I get rid of the `BEGIN TRANS` and keep the `BEGIN TRY` only?

The error I am getting is

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 9, Line 222

It seems as though sometimes it tries to create the stored procedure again even though it already exists. Should I go ahead and isolate this in a different script?

```
-- Verify that the stored procedure does not already exist.  
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#MakeColumnsNullable', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
    DROP PROCEDURE #MakeColumnsNullable;  
GO 

-- create a temporary stored procedure to Drop Constraints
CREATE PROCEDURE #MakeColumnsNullable
    @tableName VARCHAR(255),
    @columnName VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @columnType NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @constraintname SYSNAME;
    DECLARE @objectid INT 

    BEGIN 
        --Make all columns that will later be deleted NULLABLE 
        SET @columnType = (SELECT DATA_TYPE
                           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                           WHERE (TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@tableName, 'NPI.', '') 
                                  OR TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@tableName, 'FastTrak.', ''))
                             AND COLUMN_NAME = @columnName)

        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
                  WHERE Name = @columnName
                    AND Object_ID = Object_ID(@tableName))
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @tableName + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @columnName + ' ' + @columnType + ' NULL '
            EXEC (@sql)
        END
    END
END
GO

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'CreateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'CreateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'UpdateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'UpdateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'DelFlag';

        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'CreateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'CreateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'UpdateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'UpdateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'DelFlag';

        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'CreateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'CreateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'UpdateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'UpdateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'DelFlag';

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    --After COMMIT TRANSACTION drop the procedure
    DROP PROCEDURE #MakeColumnsNullable;

    /* Stored procedures TO BE REMOVED */
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'NPI.OutdatedSproc1') 
                 AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
    BEGIN
        -- Drop deprecated stored procedure OutdatedSproc1
        EXEC('DROP PROCEDURE NPI.OutdatedSproc1')
            PRINT ' NPI.OutdatedSproc1DROPPED'
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'NPI.OutdatedSproc2') 
                 AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
    BEGIN
        -- Drop Deprecated stored procedure OutdatedSproc2
        EXEC('DROP PROCEDURE NPI.OutdatedSproc2');
        PRINT ' NPI.OutdatedSproc2DROPPED';
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'NPI.OutdatedSproc3') 
                 AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
    BEGIN
        -- Drop deprecated stored procedure OutdatedSproc3
        EXEC('DROP PROCEDURE NPI.OutdatedSproc3');
        PRINT ' NPI.OutdatedSproc3DROPPED';
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @Error INT = @@ERROR;

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage       nvarchar(4000) = 
        'Error in ' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity  INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    DECLARE @ErrorState     INT = ERROR_STATE();

    PRINT @ErrorMessage;
    PRINT @ErrorSeverity;
    PRINT @ErrorState;
END CATCH
```

Comment: Sharing the error message would be a HUGE help here. But your transaction logic is all over the place. You have reasonable looking try/catch blocks but your transaction logic is a trainwreck. You have code in your catch to rollback a transaction but you don't check if one exists. Your try blocks have lots of stuff running after the transaction has been committed. You are also dropping the temporary procedure in itself. I don't know if that would even work but eludes to there being some major logical issues going on here.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for your input, what I am trying to do is create a temporary store proc, use it in a transaction block then drop the store procedure. If an error where to be encountered catch it and roll back the entire transaction.

Comment: @SeanLange With that goal in mind what changes would you recommend? Where would you drop the temp store proc?

Comment: Why use a temporary stored proc at all? What benefit does putting this into a procedure provide? For transaction handling you should have 1 transaction for the entire thing and run no code after commit.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you, we are using a store proc because it will be cleaner and easier to follow this way. I will go ahead and place all the code in the transaction block.. I believe that is where the error is being created. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @SeanLange I ran it with the whole code block inside the transaction I still get an error where it cannot create the store proc because it already exists. I dont understand why it is trying to create the store proc again.... Is it not possible to write this script with a temporary sproc being created at the start?

Comment: Temporary objects are created in tempdb, not the database your are executing it in. Still...you haven't posted the error message. I don't see how putting this into a temporary stored proc is doing anything other than making this more difficult for you. To correct how you look for them you need to look for this in tempdb like this. OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MakeColumnsNullable'

Comment: Now that you've added the Error code to the question, 50000 is a user-defined error. I'm no expert at MSSQL, but from what I've found on Google, that error code is raised by using `RAISERROR`.  This would be related to the `ERROR_MESSAGE()` most likely.

Comment: Also: It's a **STORED** procedure - as in a procedure that is **stored** inside your SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a "store" ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your feedback I realized that there were several things that were wrong:

1. The code block was not completely inside the **TRANSACTION** Block, this would cause for the stored procedure to attempt to be created again when it already existed
2. Was not using the appropriate method to look for the **TEMP** stored procedure, this has been changed to check every time we run this script
3. As @Steve-o169 said there were issues with the way the error was handled I removed  **ERROR_MESSAGE**() and **RAISEERROR**() since both of these were creating issues. Using **ltrim(str(@@ERROR))** instead so we can see the error properly
4. This helped me see that one of the reasons why this stored procedure was failing was because a column had an index dependent of it, after doing more research it seems as though making a column nullable in SQL eyes is like dropping it and recreating it. Thus the stored procedure would fail since it had this index depending on the column. I added logic to drop this index make the column nullable and re create the index afterwards.
5. Added **THROW** in the **CATCH** block

Thank you all for the help, hope this may help someone in the future.

Corrected stored procedure:

```
-- Verify that the stored procedure does not already exist.  
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MakeColumnsNullable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROC #MakeColumnsNullable
END
GO

-- create a temporary stored procedure to Drop Constraints
CREATE PROCEDURE #MakeColumnsNullable
@tableName varchar(255),
@columnName varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @columnType NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @constraintname SYSNAME;
    DECLARE @dropIndexStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @createIndexStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @indexName NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @objectid int
    BEGIN 
        --Get column type 
        SET @columnType = (SELECT DATA_TYPE
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE (TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@tableName, 'NPI.', '') OR TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@tableName, 'FastTrak.', ''))
                    AND COLUMN_NAME = @columnName)

        -- need to see if there are any references to indexes
        IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id(@tableName) AND filter_definition like '%'+ @columnName +'%' AND type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED')
        BEGIN 
            set @indexName = (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id(@tableName) AND filter_definition like '%'+ @columnName +'%' AND type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED');
            set @dropIndexStatement = N'DROP INDEX ' + @indexName + ' ON ' + @tableName + ' '
            set @createIndexStatement = N'CREATE INDEX ' + @indexName + ' ON ' + @tableName + ' (' + @columnName + ') '

            --PRINT @dropIndexStatement;
            EXEC (@dropIndexStatement)
        END

        -- Make the column nullable
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = @columnName
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(@tableName))
        BEGIN
            set @sql = N'alter table ' + @tableName + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @columnName + ' ' + @columnType + ' NULL '
            --PRINT @sql;
            EXEC (@sql)
        END

        --RECREATE INDEX IF @createIndexStatement has been SET
        IF (@createIndexStatement IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@createIndexStatement) > 0)
        BEGIN
            --PRINT @createIndexStatement;
            EXEC (@createIndexStatement)
        END
    END
END
GO

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'CreateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'CreateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'UpdateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'UpdateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table1', 'DelFlag';

        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'CreateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'CreateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'UpdateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'UpdateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table2', 'DelFlag';

        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'CreateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'CreateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'UpdateID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'UpdateComponentID';
        EXEC #MakeColumnsNullable 'NPI.Table3', 'DelFlag';

        /* SPROCS TO BE REMOVED */
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MakeColumnsNullable') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP PROC #MakeColumnsNullable
        END

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'NPI.OutdatedSproc1') 
                 AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
        BEGIN
            -- Drop deprecated stored procedure OutdatedSproc1
            EXEC('DROP PROCEDURE NPI.OutdatedSproc1')
                PRINT ' NPI.OutdatedSproc1DROPPED'
        END

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM sys.objects 
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'NPI.OutdatedSproc2') 
                    AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
        BEGIN
            -- Drop Deprecated stored procedure OutdatedSproc2
            EXEC('DROP PROCEDURE NPI.OutdatedSproc2');
            PRINT ' NPI.OutdatedSproc2DROPPED';
        END

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM sys.objects 
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'NPI.OutdatedSproc3') 
                    AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
        BEGIN
            -- Drop deprecated stored procedure OutdatedSproc3
            EXEC('DROP PROCEDURE NPI.OutdatedSproc3');
            PRINT ' NPI.OutdatedSproc3DROPPED';
        END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'TRAN ROLLEDBACK FOR SOME REASON'; 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
    END

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000) = 'Error is ' + ltrim(str(@@ERROR)) + '.';
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity  INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    DECLARE @ErrorState     INT = ERROR_STATE();

    PRINT @ErrorMessage;
    PRINT @ErrorSeverity;
    PRINT @ErrorState;

    THROW;
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is basically, keep the creation of your stored procedure (temporary) at a global level and separated script, the other questions:

> 1. What would be the correct way of creating a temporary stored procedure at the start of a script and then running a BEGIN TRANSACTION to make these columns nullable?

**Answer**: independently of the order (I think it should be created in a separated script and using a global temporary stored procedure), if you decide to keep in a TRANSACTION is because you are looking for atomicity inside your change, my only concern according to my experience is about the size of your tables and if it takes blocking and consumption of many resources.

> 2. Should I get rid of the BEGIN TRANS and keep the BEGIN TRY only?

**Answer**: Do you need atomicity as part of this change, if the answer is not you can keep only inside BEGIN TRY.